# Need habitable barge/river boat - think British canal narrowboats but faster. Engine, build, real life inspiration ideas needed

Tags: technology, travel, engines

So I have a boat which is meant for river travel, so built like a barge, flat hull etc but it's not just for cargo, think of one of those fancy modern British narrowboats with cosy furnishings etc. However I'm stuck with ideas for the engine. The setting is quite advanced, I suppose there isn't a historical parallel but it would be closer to Regency-era technology than full-blown Victorian industry. Any pointers towards historical river boats and engines will be helpful. Since the boat is used by a couple of smugglers it needs to have secret storage compartments, and though this isn't something I necessarily need help with I just thought I'd mention it. All ideas and help are appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how much flexibility you have in your available tech, but [steam powered submarines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pg_j8_NjZxw) have been a thing since the 19th century ([boats before then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steamboat)). Steam power existed for [hundreds of years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_steam_power) before then so there's time to adapt it and tweak it in the name of cool fiction if necessary (it would need to be made smaller than is strictly realistic I expect based on your description of the boat).

Comment: I believe there were/are such boats on the Rhine and other European rivers.

Comment: @futurelamb, a steam-powered submarine isn't very sneaky.

Comment: @Mark; The question does not call for "sneaky" in any way. The boat will use _"secret storage compartments"_ to do its smuggling. There are many types of smuggling, some require sneaking around officials, some require fooling them that you're meant to be there (fake papers), some require hiding what your smuggling while they search your vehicle, some require bribing them. In most of those instances (though there may be more) - a sneaky vehicle is not required, and indeed may even attract extra suspicion. Sometimes sneaking can be done in non-sneaky designed vehicles (think American Made).

Comment: @futurelamb  Thanks for all the links, will have a good look at those. Submarines are too much for my world but their engines will be interesting to look at.

Comment: @Mark, tbh, they're not smuggling very obvious things. They're book smugglers, so in my world that isn't too hard to do. Basically banned books are missing official stamps and the smugglers stamp on a fake mark. They operate on busy waterways where many fishermen and poor folk live on boats, so when their stuff is searched, they're pretty much safe unless the full boat is seized, as for the books to be recognised as banned the soldiers will have to sort through a lot of paperwork. As for why so many books are being smuggled that's getting into detail, but basically sneakiness is not important.

Comment: @akakak, using a steam-powered submarine when there's no need to is about as sneaky as waving a giant neon sign saying "Look!  Look!  I've got something to hide!".  A sensible smuggler does their best to blend in so the authorities never even look at them (successful drug smuggling in Florida, for example, is done by women in their 60s driving Honda Civics, because the police are busy paying attention to the teenage black males driving sports cars).

Answer (score 4):

**I got your engine right here!**

[image: horse drawn narrow boat]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrowboat#/media/File:Horse_drawn_cruising_on_the_Montgomery_Canal_-_geograph.org.uk_-_846074.jpg

Except there would be a kid leading the horse pulling your [narrowboat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrowboat_), not Gramps there.

Your smugglers with 1820 tech are not going to have some fancy engine.  They are not going to have a giant pedalo even though that would be cool.  They are smugglers and they don't want anyone to look twice at them.  Their boat is lugging bricks or pottery or whatever back and forth along the river or canal, just like dozens of other working riverboats.

Like any good smuggler, they disguise their smuggling with the legitimate enterprise.

If you want their boat to be able to put on a burst of speed at need, have them secretly have a mast and a sail.   The kid rides the horse home when they leave.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However I'd already considered those much too archaic for my world, and with the added trouble of busy rivers (and no large canal systems as in the UK) to hinder a horse-pulled boat like this. The world's tech is also quite flexible. But you've brought up an interesting point, I might simply be content with a mast and sail, which could be lowered when passing bridges. Thanks nevertheless for the detailed answer!

Comment: @akakak - I looked up the Regency period in Britain - that is early 1800s.  Engines were in their infancy.  I struggled to reconcile that with "quite advanced".